# Importing Products, Super attribute not allowing any other from that attribute be selected in admin panel?

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute, importexport, attribute-set

I am having an issue with importing a defined configurable product not allowing anything from that attribute set to be selected from the admin panel. I am getting results like this

[image: Import Results]

Here is an example of my configurable

```
Array
(
    [sku] => 63204
    [_store] => 
    [_attribute_set] => Belts
    [_type] => configurable
    [_category] => 
    [_root_category] => 
    [_product_websites] => base
    [fit_coats_jacket_sizes] => 
    [fit_vest_cruiser_sizes] => 
    [amconf_simple_price] => 
    [bag_size] => 
    [bag_type] => 
    [belt_width] => 
    [color] => 
    [cost] => 
    [country_of_manufacture] => 
    [created_at] => 2010-06-02 00:00:00
    [custom_design] => 
    [custom_design_from] => 
    [custom_design_to] => 
    [custom_layout_update] => 
    [description] => Descr
    [fabric] => Bridle Leather
    [gallery] => 
    [garment_size] => 
    [gift_message_available] => 
    [gift_wrapping_available] => 
    [gift_wrapping_price] => 
    [glove_size] => 
    [gun_scabbard_size] => 
    [has_options] => 1
    [hat_size] => 
    [image] => 
    [image_label] => 
    [inseam] => 
    [is_returnable] => Use config
    [manufacturer] => 
    [media_gallery] => 
    [meta_description] => 
    [meta_keyword] => 
    [meta_title] => 
    [minimal_price] => 
    [msrp] => 
    [msrp_display_actual_price_type] => Use config
    [msrp_enabled] => Use config
    [name] => 1" Leather Belt
    [news_from_date] => 
    [news_to_date] => 
    [options_container] => Product Info Column
    [page_layout] => 
    [price] => 52.00
    [related_tgtr_position_behavior] => 
    [related_tgtr_position_limit] => 
    [required_options] => 1
    [short_description] => Short Descr
    [small_image] => 
    [small_image_label] => 
    [special_from_date] => 
    [special_price] => 
    [special_to_date] => 
    [status] => 1
    [tax_class_id] => 2
    [thumbnail] => 
    [thumbnail_label] => 
    [updated_at] => 2014-10-14 16:42:33
    [upsell_tgtr_position_behavior] => 
    [upsell_tgtr_position_limit] => 
    [url_key] => 1-leather-belt
    [url_path] => 
    [visibility] => 4
    [weight] => 1.0000
    [qty] => 1.0000
    [min_qty] => 0.0000
    [use_config_min_qty] => 1
    [is_qty_decimal] => 0
    [backorders] => 0
    [use_config_backorders] => 1
    [min_sale_qty] => 1.0000
    [use_config_min_sale_qty] => 1
    [max_sale_qty] => 0.0000
    [use_config_max_sale_qty] => 1
    [is_in_stock] => 1
    [notify_stock_qty] => 
    [use_config_notify_stock_qty] => 1
    [manage_stock] => 0
    [use_config_manage_stock] => 1
    [stock_status_changed_auto] => 0
    [use_config_qty_increments] => 1
    [qty_increments] => 0.0000
    [use_config_enable_qty_inc] => 1
    [enable_qty_increments] => 0
    [is_decimal_divided] => 0
    [_links_related_sku] => 
    [_links_related_position] => 
    [_links_crosssell_sku] => 
    [_links_crosssell_position] => 
    [_links_upsell_sku] => 
    [_links_upsell_position] => 
    [_associated_sku] => 
    [_associated_default_qty] => 
    [_associated_position] => 
    [_tier_price_website] => 
    [_tier_price_customer_group] => 
    [_tier_price_qty] => 
    [_tier_price_price] => 
    [_group_price_website] => 
    [_group_price_customer_group] => 
    [_group_price_price] => 
    [_media_attribute_id] => 
    [_media_image] => 
    [_media_lable] => 
    [_media_position] => 
    [_media_is_disabled] => 
    [_super_products_sku] => 63204242204
    [_super_attribute_code] => color
    [_super_attribute_option] => Tan
    [_super_attribute_price_corr] => 
)
```

After importing a csv with contents like the pastebin below. What am i doing wrong? I've been struggling with this for hours?

http://pastebin.com/neUxKy2g

Answer (score 0):

That screenshot is from the "Associated Products" tab when viewing your configurable, right? I'd need to see the full screenshot to be sure but I suspect it's because your import has only defined a few values for its "super attributes" for this particular configurable product.

When you import a new configurable product via CSV, the _super_attribute_code and _super_attribute_option columns don't just define what subproducts you're adding but what options are possible. It looks like that's what's happened here, that "XS" is the only allowed size and "Red/Black" and "Burgundy" are the only allowed colours.

If that's the case, you can either add the other sizes and colours in the "Super product attributes configuration" part of that page in the admin, or just specify the other _super_attribute_code and _super_attribute_option values in additional rows in your CSV.

Comment: On closer inspection I can see that "Navy, XS" is available so I guess the colours haven't been restricted, or if they have Navy is a valid option too. Looks like most likely it's just the size that's the issue.